# Which of the following are subspaces of $M$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $M$ be a vector space of all $3\times 3$ real matrices and let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&3&1\\0&2&0\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}.$$ Which of the followings are subspaces of $M?$

1. $\{X\in M:XA=AX\}$
2. $\{X\in M:X+A=A+X\}$
3. $\{X\in M:\text{trace}(XA)=0\}$
4. $\{X\in M:\det(XA)=0\}$

Comment: What is your current progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$X+A=A+X$ for all $X\in M$, since matrix addition is commutative.

The trace function is additive.

Since $\det(A)\neq 0$, $\det(XA)=0$ iff $\det(X)=0$.

Comment: As Somaye suggested is only $1$ correct? I guess not.

Comment: @asstil No, "only #1 is a subspace" is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

only number 1 is subspace becuase for each $x_1 ,x_2 \in M$ we have $x_1A=Ax_1$ and $x_2A=Ax_2$ so for each $c\in F$ we will have $(cx_1+x_2)A=cx_1A+x_2A=Acx_1+Ax_2=A(cx_1+x_2)$

Comment: Nice Somaye ;-)

Comment: Why $2$ and $3$ are not? For $2$ I can see it's whole of $M.$

Comment: about number  4  det(cx_1A+x_2A)\ne Cdet(x_1A)+det(x_2A)

Comment: Sure. But what about the others?

Comment: i will tell you now

Comment: i think iam not sure about 3

Comment: hey for example x_1=[-3/2,0,0;0,0,0;0,0,3]and x_2=[-3,0,0:0,3,0;0,0,0]

Comment: then trac(x_1A)+trac(x_2A)=0 but trac((x_1+x_2)(A))\ne 0

Comment: ok asstil?you  accept it?